# how to select 6th tr's td in a html table using vba code

Tags: html, excel, html-parsing, html-tableextract, vba

1. tr----   0495024988
2. 14.08.1996
3. 04/04/130/02514/AM96/
4. 23.01.1996
5. 0495024988

**6. tr----(here the text is there which i have copy to my excel sheet)**

here i have read many post where the javascript code is given but the vba code is not there. please help me out of this.

Comment: The main question is how do you get access to the HTML from Excel VBA. Please show how you are doing that. For example, if you have access to the DOM within a browser then the further methods are not much different between JavaScript and VBA.

Comment: hi alex, the code i have used to access is pasted below.

Answer (score 0):

Sub GoToWebSiteAndPlayAroundNew()

Dim appIE As Object ' InternetExplorer.Application
Dim URL As String
Dim i As Long, strText As String

Dim doc As Object, hTable As Object, hBody As Object, hTR As Object, hTD As Object
Dim tb As Object, bb As Object, tr As Object, td As Object

Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

Dim sws As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim IE As Object

Dim vIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
URL = "http://dgft.delhi.nic.in:8100/dgft/IecPrint"

y = 1 'Column A in Excel
z = 1 'Row 1 in Excel

With appIE
.navigate URL
.Visible = True

Do While .busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

.document.getElementById("iec").Value = "0495024988"

.document.getElementById("name").Value = "AMB"

End With

On Error Resume Next

With appIE.document

Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each e In elems

If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Submit Query") Then
e.Click
Exit For
End If

Next e

End With
Set sws = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
For Each vIE In sws
'If Left(vIE.LocationURL, 4) = "http" Then 'avoid explorer windows/etc this way
            'If MsgBox("IE Window found.  The URL is:" & vbCrLf & vIE.LocationURL & vbCrLf & _
            'vbCrLf & "Do you want to see the html?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                 'Show html in a msgbox
               ' MsgBox vIE.document.body.innerHTML
                 'Or put it to a file
                 'dim vFF as long
                 'vff=freefile
                 'open "C:\thehtml.txt" for output as #vff
                 'print #vff,vie.document.body.innerhtml
                 'close #vff
           ' End If
        'End If

```
 Set doc = vIE.document
 Set hTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")


 For Each tb In hTable

    Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
    For Each bb In hBody

        Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")

        MsgBox hTR.Length
        For Each tr In hTR


             Set hTD = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
             MsgBox hTD.Length
             y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
             For Each td In hTD

               ws.Cells(z, y).Value = td.innerText
               y = y + 1
             Next td
             DoEvents
             z = z + 1

        Next tr
        Exit For
    Next bb
Exit For
```

Next tb

Next

End Sub